# csh scripting - passing variables and calling csh script from another csh script

Tags: shell, variables, scripting, csh

I am trying to understand passing two variables from one csh script to another csh script. Perform simple arithmatic function then passing the sum variable to the orginal csh script. Then outputing the sum variable to standard output and a file.

script1.sh

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv num1 3
setenv num2 2
source script2.sh
set total=$sum
echo $total > total.txt
echo $total
```

script2.sh

```
#!/bin/csh
set int1=$num1
set int2=$num2
set sum=$int1 + $int2
```

Answer (score 1):

With 'csh', the 'set' command perform simple (string) assignment, and takes a single word. The assignment 'set sum=$int +$int2' has 2 issues

- It does not use a single word
- Even the expression was combined into a single word (set sum="$int1 + $int2"), the set does not evaluate expression.

Consider instead using the '@' command which will take an expression

```
@ sum2 = $int1 + $int2
```

Sde note: For 'csh' script, the common convention is to use a '.csh' suffix. The '.sh' suffix is commonly used to files associated with sh-like shells (sh, bash, ash, ...)